# Tower of colored cubes

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

Consider a set of n cubes with colored facets (each one with a specific color
out of 4 possible ones - red, blue, green and yellow). Form the highest possible tower of k cubes ( k ≤ n ) properly rotated (12 positions of a cube), so the lateral faces of the tower will have the same color, using and evolutionary algorithm.

What I did so far:

I thought that the following representation would be suitable: an Individual could be an array of n integers, each number having a value between 1 and 12, indicating the current position of the cube (an input file contains n lines, each line shows information about the color of each face of the cube).

Then, the Population consists of multiple Individuals.

The Crossover method should create a new child(Individual), containing information from its parents (approximately half from each parent).

Now, my biggest issue is related to the Mutate and Fitness methods.
In Mutate method, if the probability of mutation (say 0.01), I should change the position of a random cube with other random position (for example, the third cube can have its position(rotation) changed from 5 to 12).
In Fitness method, I thought that I could compare, two by two, the cubes from an Individual, to see if they have common faces. If they have a common face, a "count" variable will be incremented with the number of common faces and if all the 4 lateral faces will be the same for these 2 cubes, the count will increase with another number of points. After comparing all the adjacent cubes, the count variable is returned. Our goal is to obtain as many adjacent cubes having the same lateral faces as we can, i.e. to maximize the Fitness method.

My question is the following:
How can be a rotation implemented? I mean, if a cube changes its position(rotation) from 3, to 10, how do we know the new arrangement of the faces? Or, if I perform a mutation on a cube, what is the process of rotating this cube if a random rotation number is selected?

I think that I should create a vector of 6 elements (the colors of each face) for each cube, but when the rotation value of a cube is modified, I don't know in what manner the elements of its vector of faces should be rearranged.
Shuffling them is not correct, because by doing this, two opposite faces could become adjacent, meaning that the vector doesn't represent that particular cube anymore (obviously, two opposite faces cannot be adjacent).

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure how you get 12 rotations; I get 24: 4 orientations with each of the 6 faces on the bottom.  Use a standard D6 (6-sided die) and see how many different layouts you get.

Apparently, the first thing you need to build is a something (a class?) that accurately represents a cube in any of the available orientations.  I suggest that you use a simple structure that can return the four faces in order -- say, front-right-back-left -- given a cube and the rotation number.

I think you can effectively represent a cube as three pairs of opposing sides.  Once you've represented that opposition, the remaining organization is arbitrary numbering: any valid choice is isomorphic to any other.  Each rotation will produce an interleaved sequence of two opposing pairs.  For instance, a standard D6 has opposing pairs [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)].  The first 8 rotations would put 1 and 6 on the hidden faces (top and bottom), giving you the sequence 2354 in each of its 4 rotations and their reverses.

That class is one large subsystem of your problem; the other, the genetic algorithm, you seem to have well in hand.  Stack all of your cubes randomly; "fitness" is a count of the most prevalent 4-show (sequence of 4 sides) in the stack.  At the start, this will generally be `1`, as *nothing* will match.

From there, you seem to have an appropriate handle on mutation.  You might give a higher chance of mutating a non-matching cube, or perhaps see if some cube is a half-match: two opposite faces match the "best fit" 4-show, so you merely rotate it along that axis, preserving those two faces, and swapping the other pair for the top-bottom pair (note: two directions to do that).

Does that get you moving?